# update one column based on query containing another (joined) table

Tags: postgresql, join, update

Consider the following select query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.event, s.column, e.oldcolumn
FROM section as s
INNER JOIN event as e
ON s.event = e.id
WHERE s.id = 1
```

Now I wish to update the section table so that the values are equal to the `oldcolumn` from the event table.

I tried:

```
UPDATE public."section"
SET public."section".column = public."event".oldcolumn
FROM public."section"
INNER JOIN public."event"
on public."section".event = public."event".id
WHERE s.id = 1
```

However this, on postgresql, returned the following error:

```
ERROR:  table name "section" specified more than once
SQL state: 42712
```

How would I do such a thing, using joins inside an update query?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.9) has examples for joined updates, and the error message tells you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: Check :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I don't use PostgreSQL but I'm pretty familiar with SQL Server.

From what I understand in the PostgreSQL documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-update.html), I think the error you are getting is caused by the inclusion of `public."section" INNER JOIN` in your `FROM` statement. When using `UPDATE` you specify the table you are updating so adding `public."section"` in the `FROM` is not necessary. Per the documentation "Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_item)."

If you change your code to what I have below, I think it would resolve your issue. Though I'm not sure about the quotation marks you have, I just copied your format. The main difference being, only have the tables you're joining to in the `FROM` and move the `ON` to the `WHERE`.

```
UPDATE public."section"
SET public."section".column = public."event".oldcolumn
FROM public."event"
WHERE public."section".event = public."event".id AND public."section".id = 1
```

Comment: This won't work in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assume you were referring to the CTE syntax. I think I found what the issue was. Will it work in Postgres now?

Comment: It will work, but it's way too complicated (and inefficient)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I removed the CTE suggestion. It's definitely helpful in SQL Server, but I agree I don't see the benefit in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6) you should not repeat the target table in the FROM clause.

So your UPDATE should be like this:

```
UPDATE public."section" s
  SET column = evt.oldcolumn
FROM public."event" evt
WHERE s.event = evt.id
  AND s.id = 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a complete example, but check the update sentence at the end also check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating)

```
DECLARE @section TABLE 
(
    id  INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    event int,
    [column] int
);

INSERT INTO @section(id, event,[column])
VALUES
    (1,3,77),
    (2,2,55),
    (3,4,88),
    (4,6,44),
    (5,1,33);

DECLARE @event TABLE
(
    id  INT PRIMARY KEY,     
    oldcolumn int
);

INSERT INTO @event(id, oldcolumn)
VALUES
    (1,177),
    (2,155),
    (3,188),
    (4,144),
    (5,133);

SELECT * FROM @section s

SELECT s.id, s.event, s.[column], e.oldcolumn
FROM @section s
INNER JOIN @event e ON s.event = e.id
WHERE s.id = 1

UPDATE s
SET s.[column] = e.oldcolumn
FROM @section s
INNER JOIN @event e ON s.event = e.id
WHERE s.id = 1

SELECT * FROM @section s
```